# HTML forms with PHP script

Tags: php, html, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to enter a record in the database. This record consists of the following :
1) Unique facebook id
2) name
3) Favorite car of the person

While the first parameter I get using the graph API from facebook, the other two are entered by the user using HTML forms using some code like this :

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
            Name <input type="text" name="Name" /></br>
            Fav car: <input type="text" name="car" /></br>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
```

Now the "insert.php" script will insert the record with the database. How can I pass the first parameter, i.e. the ID, which is something that insert.php needs, but it is not a user-entered parameter.

Comment: You could pass it as a hidden input and access it at insert.php in the $_POST array

Comment: @xbonez : How can I pass a hidden input ?

Comment: <input style="display:none;" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hidden parameter as follows (I assume your PHP variable containing the ID is `$facebookId`):

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="facebook_id" id="facebook_id" value="<?php echo $facebookId?>"/>
   Name <input type="text" name="Name" /></br>
   Fav car: <input type="text" name="car" /></br>
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You could also use pure Javascript (I assume you stored the Facebook GraphID response in `facebookResponse`)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       document.getElementById("facebook_id").value = facebookResponse["id"];
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass it as a hidden input from within your form.

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    Name <input type="text" name="Name" /></br>
    Fav car: <input type="text" name="car" /></br>
    <input name="fbID" type="hidden" value="{value_to_pass_here}" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This way the `fbID` input won't be exposed in the front end of your website but will get POSTed to your server side script along with other input parameters, and you can access it in `index.php` at `$_POST['fbID'];`

The value you want to pass, in your case the FB Key, should be in the `value` attribute of this input field.